# How to prevent .htaccess rule adding endlessly repeated parameter at the end of the URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm building a website (in Joomla 4, if that's relevant), and I'm trying to use .htaccess to redirect URLs like this:

```
index.php/characters
```

... to URLs like this:

```
index.php/characters?reset=true
```

... but leave URLs like this alone:

```
index.php/characters?search=fred
```

I used https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ to test the following rules, and the simulation looked like it would achieve exactly what I want:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!search)
  RewriteRule index.php/characters /index.php/characters?reset=true [L,R,QSA]
```

But this gives me endless redirects which look like this:

```
index.php/characters?reset=true&reset=true&reset=true&reset=true&reset=true&reset=true&reset=true&reset=true (etc)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a redirect rule like this:

```sh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)(search|reset)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/characters/?$ /$0?reset=true [L,R,QSA]
```

Negative condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)(search|reset)=`  will skip the rule if query string has a parameter that starts with `search=` or `reset=`.

Comment: It sure did - thank you! One more question - if I want to apply the same rule to other pages, do I need to duplicate both of those lines for each page? I tried just duplicating the second line with the name of another page, but it only seemed to work for the first page ('characters')...

Comment: Can you provide few examples of source and target URLs of the  redirections that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure - they're all the same basic structure: index.php/characters, index.php/weapons, index.php/builds ... etc.

Comment: Then change pattern to `RewriteRule ^index\.php/(?:characters|weapons|builds)/?$ /$0?reset=true [L,R,QSA]`